# Accessing properties of class through class interface

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, oop

Why can't I access the base class (testClass) properties through it's interface (ItestClass)?
I have created the interface to avoid the actual Control (winforms/wpf) properties to be visible in the third class (newClass). if that is not possible is there a better way?

```
public class testClass : Control, ItestClass
{
    public int Property1 { set; get; }
    public int Property2 { set; get; }
    public testClass() { }
}
public interface ItestClass
{
    int Property1 { get; set; }
    int Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class newClass : ItestClass
{
    public newClass()
    {
        // Why are the following statements are not possible?
        Property1 = 1;
        // OR
        this.Property1 = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interface doesn't actually implement the properties -- you will still need to define them in the implementing class:

```
public class newClass : ItestClass
{
    int Property1 { get; set; }
    int Property2 { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

**Edit**

C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, so you can't have `testClass` inherit both `Control` and another concrete class.  You could always use composition instead, though.  For example:

```
public interface ItestClassProps
{
    public ItestClass TestClassProps { get; set; }
}

public class testClass : Control, ItestClassProps
{
    public ItestClass TestClassProps { set; get; }

    public testClass() { }
}
```

Comment: @mason not in `newClass`.

Comment: the thing is I simply didn't want to directly inherit testClass, as it would also show all the Control properties, instead I inherited it's interface to avoid that.

Comment: so basically I need to redefine them in third class (newClass)?

Comment: @Johnny yes, since C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, you have to use composition in this case.

Comment: @Johnny - Yes, but note that `newClass` *won't share values* with `testClass`.  It's an entirely separate class which is interchangeable with a `testClass` in any circumstance where you want an `ItestClass`.

Comment: @McGarnagle, thanks for your input, problem is I have lots of properties and methods in the base class, is there another way to hide the Control properties?

Comment: @Johnny - Make them public and access it from another unrelated class which has a `testClass` variable or property.

Comment: @Bobson well how about, for those consumers that should see the encapsulated version of the class, pass it a reference to `ItestClass` instead of the concrete class?

Comment: @McGarnagle, I think that is pretty much what im looking for

Comment: @Johnny so basically, either use `encapsulation` by passing a reference to "ItestClass" instead of "testClass", *or* use `composition` by giving "testClass" an "ItestClass" property (see my edit above).